# I’m doing a form filling project that stores data from react to nodejs and then to database. I am unable to pass the data from react to node

Tags: reactjs, formik

I’m doing a form filling project that stores data from react to nodejs and then to database. I am unable to pass the data from react to node when using FORMIK I need to know what extra should I code to solve the issue
my code for your reference :

Please find the following code with the issue.

```
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

const formValidation = yup.object({
  NameoftheUPSIProject: yup
    .string()
    .required("Fill the Name of the UPSI Project"),

  InformationSharedBy: yup.string().required("Fill the Information Shared By"),

  InfoSharedwithrespectto: yup.string().required("A radio option is required"),

  InsiderTypes: yup.string().required("Fill the Insider Types"),

  ContactPerson: yup.string().required("Fill the Contact Person"),

  NameoftheOrganization: yup
    .string()
    .required("Fill the  Name of the Organization"),

  DateofSharing: yup.string().required("Fill the Date and Time of Sharing"),

  ParticularofInformationShared: yup
    .string()
    .required("Fill the Particular of Information Shared"),

  PurposeofSharing: yup.string().required("Fill the Purpose of Sharing"),

  ModeofSharing: yup.string().required("Fill the Mode of Sharing"),
});

const apple = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  fetch(`localhost:5000/details`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
};

const DetailsList = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      NameoftheUPSIProject: "",
      InformationSharedBy: "",
      InfoSharedwithrespectto: "",
      InsiderTypes: "",
      ContactPerson: "",
      NameoftheOrganization: "",
      DateofSharing: "",
      ParticularofInformationShared: "",
      PurposeofSharing: "",
      ModeofSharing: "",
    },
    validationSchema: formValidation,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      try {
        setloading(true);
        await axios.post(`http:localhost:5000/api/detailsnewform`, values);
        setloading(false);
        alert("Form Created Successfully");
        formik.resetForm();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <div>
          {/* <div class="mb-3 row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com"/>
    </div> */}
          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Name of the UPSI Project:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Information Shared By:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Info Shared with respect to:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="radio" name="reason" value="Fit Description" />
              Designated Person
              <div>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="Fit Description" />
                Insider
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" name="reason" value="Fit Description" />
                UPSI Project
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Insider Types:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select
                class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3"
                aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
              >
                <option selected>Director</option>
                <option value="1">Managing Director</option>
                <option value="2">Independent Director</option>
                <option value="3">CFO</option>
                <option value="4">Company Secretary</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Insider Signed Confidentially Agreement:
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label
              for="text"
              class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
              style={{ color: "red" }}
            >
              No Confidentially Agreement Signed
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Contact Person:
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Type of Organization:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                Partnership
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Name of the Organization:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Date and Time of Sharing:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="date" id="date" name="trip-start" />
              <script src="date.js"></script>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Particular of Information Shared:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3 row">
            <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
              Purpose of Sharing:
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                Mode of Sharing:
              </label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select
                  class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3"
                  aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
                >
                  <option selected>Email</option>
                  <option value="1">Physical</option>
                  <option value="2">Pendrive</option>
                </select>

                <div class="mb-3 row">
                  {/* <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> */}
                  <button type="submit" className="button">
                    SUBMIT
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script></script>
    </form>
  );
};
export default DetailsList;
```

I tried using above code but unable to pass the data

Comment: Shall I provide a sample that is working? then you can go thought it and fix your issues?

Comment: sure Radika Dilanka

Comment: Please do not add a link to your code. See [mre] and [edit] the question to contain all relevant code within the question itself. Links can rot, people might not be able to access the website, there might be licensing issues etc.

Comment: okay i will follow the same

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using formik

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Button, Grid, Typography, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material';

const SignupForm = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant='h4' align='center' gutterBottom>
        Signup
      </Typography>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          confirmPassword: '',
          address: '',
          phone: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          firstName: Yup.string().required('First name is required'),
          lastName: Yup.string().required('Last name is required'),
          email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Email is required'),
          password: Yup.string()
            .required('Password is required')
            .min(8, 'Password is too short - should be 8 characters or longer')
            .matches(
              /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/,
              'Password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character',
            ),
          confirmPassword: Yup.string()
            .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
            .required('Confirm password is required'),
          address: Yup.string().required('Address is required'),
          phone: Yup.string()
            .matches(/^\+?\d{10,14}$/, 'Invalid phone number')
            .required('Phone number is required'),
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
          }, 400);
        }}
      >
        {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.firstName && !!errors.firstName}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='firstName'>First Name</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='firstName' name='firstName' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='firstName' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.lastName && !!errors.lastName}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='lastName'>Last Name</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='lastName' name='lastName' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='lastName' />{' '}
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.email && !!errors.email}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='email'>Email</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='email' name='email' type='email' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='email' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.password && !!errors.password}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='password'>Password</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='password' name='password' type='password' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='password' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.confirmPassword && !!errors.confirmPassword}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='confirmPassword'>Confirm Password</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='confirmPassword' name='confirmPassword' type='password' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='confirmPassword' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.address && !!errors.address}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='address'>Address</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='address' name='address' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='address' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl fullWidth error={touched.phone && !!errors.phone}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor='phone'>Phone</InputLabel>
                  <Field as={Input} id='phone' name='phone' variant='outlined' />
                  <FormHelperText>
                    <ErrorMessage name='phone' />
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button variant='contained' color='primary' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;
```

Then inside the onSubmit function you can call the backend.

here you can find the repo https://github.com/radika-insfra/formik-sample

I've checked your code the axios call should be like this,

```
  axios
    .post(`http:localhost:5000/api/detailsnewform`, values)
    .then((response) => {
    
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
     console.log(e)
    });
```

if you need help in nodejs side, please have a comment.